# CSS/JS Checked checkbox should "line out" an <li> element in a To Do List Application

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

Im creating a classic To Do list application in html/JS/CSS, where i have the following functionality :

- User types inn his/hers Task
- The task is then printet below with a checkbox on the same line
- The task is also stored in an object with a timestamp.
- All new tasks are added above old ones.

How can i solve the following problem, using ONLY css :

When the user checks the checkbox, the task on the corresponding line should be "lined out" so that it becomes clear that its completed.

I made a jsfiddle, but i cant make it run there, anyway here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/fm6cbuu9/2/

What i have so far :

JS :

```
var tasks = {}


function addTask(){
var task = document.getElementById("inn").value
var ol = document.getElementById("ol")
var li = document.createElement("li")
var d = new Date()
var box = document.createElement("input")
        box.type = "checkbox"
        box.id = "box"

li.appendChild(box)
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task))
ol.insertBefore(li, ol.childNodes[0])

tasks[d.getTime()] = task
console.log(tasks)
```

}

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] + li {
text-decoration: overline;
```

}

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
        <h1> To Do List </h1>

        <form id="skjema">
        Enter Task: <input type="text" id="inn" required="true">
                    <button type="button" onclick="addTask()"> Submit Task       </button> <br>
        Count task: <input type="text" id="ut" disabled="true">
        </form>

        <ol id="ol">

        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a text node for the task name, put it inside of a label for the checkbox. Then you just target the label next to the checked box in your CSS:

```js
var tasks = {}

window.addTask = function(){
 var task = document.getElementById("inn").value;
 var ol = document.getElementById("ol");
 var li = document.createElement("li");
 var d = new Date();
 var taskId = d.getTime();
 var box = document.createElement("input"); 
  box.type = "checkbox";
  box.id = "box-" + taskId;
 var label = document.createElement("label");
  label.setAttribute("for", "box-" + taskId);
  label.innerHTML = task;

 li.appendChild(box);
 li.appendChild(label);
 ol.insertBefore(li, ol.childNodes[0]);
 
 tasks[taskId] = task;
 console.log(tasks);
}
```

```css
#container {
 display: block;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: lightgray;
 border-radius: 10px;
 width: 800px;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 0;
 padding: 20px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
 text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
 <title>To do list</title>

<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="inner">
   <h1> To Do List </h1>
   
   <form id="skjema">
   Enter Task: <input type="text" id="inn" required="true">
      <button type="button" onclick="addTask()"> Submit Task </button> <br>
   Count task: <input type="text" id="ut" disabled="true">
   </form>

   <ol id="ol">
   
   </ol>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```